# Не обнуляется checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Все просто. Есть checkbox при нажатии на него идет запрос ajax, выборка и вывод результата.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="available" value="3" onClick="setAvailable(this);" /> Есть в наличии
```

Функция ajax

```
function setAvailable(link){

    form= $("form[name=filterForm]");
    form.find("[name=page]").val(0);
    form.find("[name=available]").val($(link).val());
    data= form.serialize();
    $(".cap").css({display:"block"});
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: data,
        success: function(answer) {
            $(".cap").css({display:"none"});
            $(".blockContentCategory").empty();
            $(".blockContentCategory").append(answer);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Что происходит на сервере

```
function getProductList(){
        $this->load->helper('text');
        $this->load->model("ajax_model");
        $data['content']= "product List";
        $post= $this->input->post();

        $scID= $post['scID'];
        $cID= $post['cID'];
        $filter= $this->ajax_model->getFilterFromGet($post);
        $filter_brand= $this->ajax_model->getFilterFromGet_brand($post);

        $res= $this->ajax_model->getProductList($cID,$scID,$filter,array("min"=>$post['priceFrom'],"max"=>$post['priceTo']),$post['sort'],$post['page'],$post['listLength'], $post['available']);
        $data['productList']= $res['products'];
        $data['viewOptions']= $res['viewOptions'];
        $this->load->view('/ajax/productList',$data);
    }
```

Все работает нормально, но потом я нажимаю еще раз, checkbox Должен сниматься а он не снгимается, в чем проблема?

[Вот ссылка на пример.](http://cosmetica-optom.kz/catalog/lico/pudry)

Нажмите на галочку есть в наличии, а потом еще раз на нее

Comment: У вас там более серьезные проблемы :) - `A Database Error Occurred`

Comment: @splash58 пожалуйста обновите кэш. Хостинг что то долго держит кэш у себя

Comment: A Database Error Occurred  -  кеши не спасают )

Comment: Спустя 10 часов кэши по прежнему не спасают)) Вы бы хоть ошибки такие скрывали на продакшене.

Comment: @DaemonHK капец это мой жесткий косяк, сегодня поправлю))) блин просто так задал вопрос не минисуйте плиз!

Comment: @duddeniska я вопросы не минусую, рейтинг дороже))